# ConfigureAwait(false) in WebAPI controller

Tags: c#, async-await, asp.net-web-api2, sonarlint

Should SonarLint fire [S3216](http://www.sonarlint.org/visualstudio/rules/index.html#version=1.7.0&ruleId=S3216&tags=) in an ASP.NET Web API controller? It seems that this rule is for desktop applications, in ASP.NET the context is totally different, there's no danger of deadlocks. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@VictorGrigoriu, we are only checking if the output kind of a compilation unit is a DLL or not, and we report issues only in DLLs. You are right that we report on cases when in a DLL you still need to switch back to the original context. In general it's a very hard thing to figure out, but we could add a check for top level web app assemblies. We need to come up with a good way to do that or disable the rule by default to not generate false positives.

I've created a ticket to track this problem: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLVS-790.

Other options until we come up with a permanent solution: you can disable this rule locally on the given project if you feel it's an annoyance. To do that, you'll need to edit the project's ruleset file through "references/analyzers/open active rule set"

Comment: Thanks for looking into it!

Answer (score 5):

You should still use `ConfigureAwait(false)` in WebAPI when you don't need to capture the context.

`ConfigureAwait` controls whether to resume on the captured `SynchronizationContext` or not. It's true that this is a more painful issue in UI apps, but it's relevant everywhere there's a `SynchronizationContext` which is all UI apps and all asp.net apps.

In UI apps the resource `SynchronizationContext` manages is the single UI thread so you can deadlock if you block it. In asp.net apps the resource is the request context and you are able to deadlock on it as well.

You can avoid using `ConfigureAwait` in console applications or windows services, though it's still a good practice to keep using it where appropriate.

Comment: But: "You should not use ConfigureAwait when you have code after the await in the method that needs the context. [...] For ASP.NET apps, this includes any code that uses HttpContext.Current or builds an ASP.NET response, including return statements in controller actions." (from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)). My understanding is that yes, in a library you should always be using `ConfigureAwait(false)`, but in GUI code or in a controller it depends on what you're doing after the await.

Comment: @VictorGrigoriu of course. If you need the context (in UI or asp.net) then let await capture it. You only need `ConfigureAwait(false)` when the context isn't needed, but it doesn't matter whether it's a "desktop app" or a WebAPI app.

Comment: What I was saying is that SonarLint shouldn't flag this as a violation in Web API controller methods, because it depends.

Comment: @VictorGrigoriu I have no idea what SonarLint is. But it flags for UI apps.. there's no reason it shouldn't for web apps.

Comment: It's a kind of FxCop built on Roslyn.